# Error `ssh not found` in terminal Android

Tags: ssh, terminal

I'm trying to use `ssh` in the app `Terminal Emulator` in `Android`, but it gives me the error `/system/bin/sh: ssh: not found`.

This is strange to me, since I also use `ssh` in the apps `AndFTP` and `SSH Server` and they work just fine.

When I then try `find -name *ssh*` in the root directory in an attempt to find the `ssh` program I get the error `/system/bin/sh: find: not found`.

Are perhaps all the symbolic links to these standard programs missing?

Comment: Most likely those apps bring their own implementation of `ssh` along. AFAIK there is no SSH installed on Android by default – though for rooted devices, there might be versions of Busybox offering that. The latter might also be true for the `find` command (at least it is on the devices I own).